# JS add a variable with ++ doesn't work inside a callback function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build my stopwatch for an assignment.

At first, I built my lap function in this way

```js
  handleClickLap: function(){
    $('#lap').click(function(event){
    if (Stopwatch.isRunning) {
      let lapCounter = 0;
      lapCounter = lapCounter + 1;
      console.log(lapCounter);
    })
```

and it was working perfectly.

I read carefully the assignment then I had to rewrite my code like this

```js
lap: function(){
    if (Stopwatch.isRunning) {
    let lapCounter = 0;
    lapCounter ++;
     console.log(lapCounter);
    }
  }


  handleClickLap: function(){
$('#lap').click(function(event){
  Stopwatch.lap();

})
```

I call all my function here

```js
window.onload = function(){
  AppController.handleClickStart();
  AppController.handleClickStopReset();
  AppController.handleClickLap();
};
```

The problem is, lap: function() dosen't run lapCounter ++; in never updates the counter i also tried ++ lapcounter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because a line before the `++` you're re-declaring the variable: `let lapCounter = 0;` ?

Comment: did the original code work perfectly? I think it will just always log `1`...

Comment: @alfasin you are so right, I'm really tired.

Answer (score 2):

oh, no, read the comment. that is almost certainly it heh. credit to @alfasin (as in give him the green check if he leaves an answer). but hold the lap count outside of the function.. e.g.

```
  {~/Desktop}$  cat test.js 
var obj = {
  lapCount: 0,
  addLap: function() {
    this.lapCount++;
    console.log(this.lapCount);
  }
}
obj.addLap()
obj.addLap()
  {~/Desktop}$  node test.js 
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt provide info on AppController and Stopwatch, I slightly tweaked your code. Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  function lap (){
    Stopwatch = {
        isRunning : true
       }
      if (Stopwatch.isRunning) {
      let lapCounter = 0;
      lapCounter ++;
       console.log(lapCounter);
      }
    }

     $('#lap').click(function(event){ 
       lap();
     })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lap">
lap
</div>
```